# Absolute positioned elements inside a float

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float, css-position

I have a stack of imgs overlaying one-another which are shown/hidden as needed. For these images to overlap I am forced to use position:absolute(I am fading between them so I need at least two images on-top of one-another at a time). Their container div is floated, but the images' height varies so I cannot set a fixed height on this parent container. I need their container to accurately reflect their height as there is another floated div that clears the container which needs to sit below the image, whatever height it is.

Is there any way of achieving this without using javascript to adjust the height of the container appropriately for each image?

Here is a link to the page as it is at the moment. I am using images with identical heights but I would like to be able to vary the height of the images.

http://www.unwalked.com/

Comment: Can you show this in a jsFiddle? I'm not sure I grasp the problem the way you describe it.

Comment: Sounds something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dJdXX/30/ Dond't have time to mess with it further, but I think that shows the problem.

Comment: In short you want the parent (P) of an absolute position element (E) to adjust its height based E.height? If so, you cannot do this without javascript because E is no longer a child of P since position absolute removes it from the flow.

Comment: Thanks all. I've added a link to the page to my question

Comment: @Eric Lennartsoon Yes. That's about it.

Comment: @Bazzz Yes. This is what I understood. Was wondering if I was missing something

Answer (score 0):

What if you don't make all the child images absolutely positioned, instead only temporarily set `position: absolute;` to the image that's being faded away? That way the container would naturally resize to fit active image.

Comment: That's nice thinking. However if the faded out image was taller than the faded in image, the floated container would then contract the the fading in image's height, leaving the fading out image overlapping its bottom edge.

Comment: Yes, this is true. But how do you want it to behave then? The best approach would be to smoothly animate container height change but that  involves javascript (I don't think you can make this with CSS transitions but maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: Yes I think I will have to use javascript somewhere; my question was whether all of this was possible without using javascript. Your answer is very close, but not quite there.

Comment: Well I guess it's the best you can do without setting container height via JavaScript...